# How to import a range of a sheet without specific cells?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I want to import data from one sheet to another sheet. The sheet is containing data under the date. The range i want to import is containing values named "APP-XX" and "KRL-XX". And there is a value just under specified value. I want to import the values in another sheet which has the phrase "APP" including the number(XX). but not "KRL-XX" Please have a look at the below screen shot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcEG8.jpg)

In picture, I want to import all the cells except "KRL-XX" and the values just below of this. **Actually I want to import the whole sheets to another sheet except cells containing "KRL-XX" and the values below "KRL-XX".**

Can you please let me know the formula or ways to import it on another sheet???
A link is given below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NTfGVDR04cFoTLsjcKKQvplXyFGL1x2Z3FcwxrvKLHs/edit#gid=1130925705

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it.

```
function everythingExcept() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet66');
    var des=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet67');
    var rng=sht.getDataRange();
    var rngA=rng.getValues();
    var rngB=rng.getBackgrounds();
    var re=/(SPL-\d{2}|BPL-\d{2})/
    for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
    {
      for(var j=0;j<rngA[0].length;j++)
      {
        if(rngA[i][j])
        {
          if(String(rngA[i][j]).match(re))
          {
            rngA[i][j]='';
            rngA[i+1][j]='';
            rngB[i][j]='#ffffff';
            rngB[i][j]='#ffffff';
          }
        }
      }
    }
    des.getRange(1,1,rngA.length,rngA[0].length).setValues(rngA);
    des.getRange(1,1,rngA.length,rngA[0].length).setBackgrounds(rngB);
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, Thanks for your reply. But I am facing an error saying "TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null. (line 6, file "Code")"

Comment: Did you edit the sheet names to agree with your spreadsheet? In the getSheetByName method

Comment: Yes I have editing just like function everythingExcept() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var des=ss.getSheetByName('APP');
    var rng=sht.getDataRange();                                                                                                         

sheet name edited by Sheet1 and des sheet name by APP, but cant understand that what will be the sht.getDataRange()
Can you please sort it out?

Regards.

Comment: The error Indicates that sht is undefined because there is a getDataRange method. I'll go to the link and take a look at it.

Comment: I went into your sheet link and added the new function and modified the sheet name from Sheet1 to Sheet 1 and that ran on your spreadsheet.  So I guess all is well.  Hope that works for you.

Comment: I am really sorry Cooper. I can't run the function. Actually i have very poor knowledge in scripting. Can you add the function in my given link so that i can study on it and do practice myself? 
Thanks in advance for your valuable response.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I  am looking for a solution regarding google script. Can I ask you here or in a different post?

Comment: Let's keep it simple and stick with one question per post.

Comment: Hi Cooper, Hope you are well. knocking you, facing a new query with the same sheet. Previously I had two variable,- APP and KRL. But Now i have three variables, -KPL,SPL,BPL. Could you please let me know the appropriate code that will import only KPL-XX cells and just the value of its below. But not SPL and BPL. For more please follow the link above.
Tahnks in advance.

Regards,
Shazzad

Comment: Thanks a ton Cooper...
You have made it :)

Comment: hi Cooper i have asked another question. can i share the link with you here??

Comment: Sure,, what's the link?

Comment: Hi Cooper, 
I want to set a formula to calculate an equation like Y=X+5 where Y is an calculated constant value generated by another formula depending on X. is there any solution.
Sorry for commenting here.